# Session not working correctly on PHP 7.3 but it works fine in 7.0

Tags: php, session

I'm having trouble with a login system using PHP. I have a file called `session.php` which I include inside another PHP file called `index.php`.

This is the code inside:

```
<?php
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
        session_start();
    }

    $user = null;

    include 'user.php';
    include 'connection.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['myweb-login'])){
        $id = $_SESSION['myweb-login'];

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, username, active_token, verified, wants_verification FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?');
        $stmt->execute([$id]);

        $userDb = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!$userDb){
            unset($_SESSION['myweb-login']);
        }else{
            $user = new User($userDb['id'], $userDb['username'], $userDb['active_token'], $userDb['verified'], $userDb['wants_verification']);
        }
    }
?>
```

It works fine in my machine using XAMPP with PHP 7.3. If I upload it to an apache server with PHP 7.3 (as well) and go into `index.php`;

I then check the value of `$user` and it's `NULL`.

However if I switch to PHP 7.0 it works just fine and `$user` is now an object as it should be.

I need to use PHP 7.3 because of compatibility with a library.

Also, if you go to the `session.php` file directly instead of including it from another file it works fine (even with PHP 7.3).

I've tried:

- Putting the `session_start()` bit inside the `index.php` at the start of the file.
- Making `index.php` content nothing but `include 'session.

But got nothing.

Also, I don't have access to the logs so I can't check there.

I tried var_dumping stuff to see if the `session.php` file is being called at all and up until the `if(isset($_SESSION['myweb-login'])){` line it shows stuff but nothing after...

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question since nothing inside `if(isset($_SESSION['myweb-login'])){` is running. What is the output of `var_dump($_SESSION)`?

Comment: No, `var_dump($_SESSION)` is NULL.

Comment: That narrows things down. How about `var_dump(session_status())`?

Comment: it returns `int (1)`. Interestingly, I copied the code from the `index.php`, copied it into another file and there it works. Maybe the `index.php` has some metadata which breaks it? Or some property is being cached or something?

Comment: Maybe. Repeat all of the above from inside index.php after the the include statement for session.php.

Comment: The same happens. Or maybe is some browser issue. I did some testing: if I delete the file. Reload the browser tab, and then reupload the file it works fine. So most likely is a browser issue.

Comment: Maybe you have white space before `<?php` or BOM?

Comment: I thought of that but I tried just deleting the file from the server and reuploading and it works fine so it's not that

Answer (score 0):

Check the session parameters in phpinfo.php

The session parameter "session.save_path" was set:  \xampp\tmp".

**Customize the php.ini**

I have modified this path to the real path to this directory. In my case "session.save_path="C:\xampp\tmp"

After a restart of Apache the session could be written and read again.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue on PHP 7.3

Removing the if block for `session_start();` and putting `session_start();` at the top of my includes resolved the issue.