# Why does my code in php works quite well in php 7.1 but not work when I change the domain in 7.3 version?

Tags: php, mysql, session-cookies, php-7.3

I am working to upgrade my domain in php 7.3 but when I do that one of my quiz.php file not work it says :

> Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set).

I mention that in 7.1 it works quite well so I think the problem is to my function.php file in function sec_session. I will show you the code without any change from 7.1.

```
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';
 
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name 
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

Comment: rzfm: https://www.php.net/manual/de/migration73.php

Or use the search function in stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030504/session-not-working-correctly-on-php-7-3-but-it-works-fine-in-7-0


Check the session parameters in phpinfo.php

The session parameter "session.save_path" was set: \xampp\tmp".

Customize the php.ini

I have modified this path to the real path to this directory. In my case "session.save_path="C:\xampp\tmp"

After a restart of Apache the session could be written and read again.

Comment: I have tried a lot reading the manual even I try with rector code to make automatically but I failed. I think is something to this $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();

Comment: It should be noted that this gets the session cookie ini file parameters, not the parameters from the cookie itself.

ie. if you set the cookie lifetime using session_set_cookie_params(12345) and then try to use session_get_cookie_params, you will not get back 12345. Instead, you will get the lifetime set in the ini file.

maybe you php.ini is wrong, or you have not restart apache or something after change settings.